# Python PyQt5 MVC framework use of lambdas not working

Tags: python, model-view-controller, lambda, pyqt5

Good Evening,

I am working on one of my first Python programs utilizing the MVC framework.  I have looked at several tutorials and examples of MVC and I followed a youTube series of creating a calulator using MVC from Life in Code.  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCb__or4F5GkZLGYBhvfa5hg/featured

I am running into an issue with my program and I can't figure out why, I believe I have narrowed the issue down to the "View" class doesn't not see the "Controller" class to pass the function.  I just don't know why.  I am doing what I believe to be the same thing as Life in Code is doing with his example.

atdsController.py

```
import sys
from atdsCreatorUi import displayUi
#from atdsModel import atdsModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class atdsController:

    def __init__(self):
        #self.model = atdsModel()
        self.view = displayUi(self)

    def on_button_click(self, btnTxt):
    
        print("I'm back in controller")
        #file = self.model.openFile()

def main():
    atdsFileCreator = QApplication(sys.argv)
    atdsFileCreator.setStyle('Fusion')

    #Show GUI
    view = displayUi(QMainWindow)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(atdsFileCreator.exec_())
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

atdsCreatorUi.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QDateTime, QTimer, QMetaObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow,
    QFrame,
    QWidget,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QGridLayout,
    QGroupBox,
    QLabel,
    QPushButton,
    QLineEdit,
    QFileDialog,
    QTableWidget,
    QHeaderView,
    QMenuBar,
    QProgressBar,
    QStatusBar,
    QAction,
    QWidgetAction,
    QToolBar,
    QPlainTextEdit)

__version__ = "1.0"
__author__ = "Daniel DeWitte"

ERROR_MSG = 'ERROR'

class VLine(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VLine, self).__init__()
        self.setFrameShape(self.VLine|self.Sunken)
    
class displayUi(QMainWindow):
        
    def _createLeftLayout(self):
    
            leftLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    
        # Create Buttons
        loadFile = QPushButton("Load File")
        #btnTxt = loadFile.text()
        loadFile.clicked.connect(lambda checked, btnTxt = loadFile.text(): 
self.controller.on_button_click(btnTxt))
        loadFile.setFont(QFont('Times', 16))
        leftLayout.addWidget(loadFile)
    
        # Create Header Information
        header = QGroupBox("Imported File Information:")
        header.setObjectName("Header")
        header.setStyleSheet("""QGroupBox#Header {border: 1px solid gray;
                             border-radius: 5px; margin-top: 0.5em;
                             font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;}
                             QGroupBox:title {subcontrol-origin: margin;
                             subcontrol-position: top center; padding: 0px 0px;}""")
    
        headerInfo = QGridLayout()
    
        # Create QLineEdits()
        empNum = QLineEdit()
        empNum.setPlaceholderText("Employee Number")
        empNum.setReadOnly(True)
        empNum.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        file = QLineEdit()
        file.setPlaceholderText("File selected for conversion")
        file.setReadOnly(True)
        file.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        testType = QLineEdit()
        testType.setPlaceholderText("Test to be converted")
        testType.setReadOnly(True)
        testType.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        partNum = QLineEdit()
        partNum.setPlaceholderText("Part Number of UUT")
        partNum.setReadOnly(True)
        partNum.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        serialNum = QLineEdit()
        serialNum.setPlaceholderText("Serial Number of UUT")
        serialNum.setReadOnly(True)
        serialNum.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        testStand = QLineEdit()
        testStand.setPlaceholderText("Test stand test was performed on")
        testStand.setReadOnly(True)
        testStand.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        standCal = QLineEdit()
        standCal.setPlaceholderText("Calibration date of Test Stand")
        standCal.setReadOnly(True)
        standCal.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        swBuildName = QLineEdit()
        swBuildName.setPlaceholderText("OFP SW Version")
        swBuildName.setReadOnly(True)
        swBuildName.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        buildName = QLineEdit()
        buildName.setPlaceholderText("Relay Emulator Tools SW Version")
        buildName.setReadOnly(True)
        buildName.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        buildToolsName = QLineEdit()
        buildToolsName.setPlaceholderText("OM Build Tools SW Version")
        buildToolsName.setReadOnly(True)
        buildToolsName.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        supportBuildName = QLineEdit()
        supportBuildName.setPlaceholderText("Support Tools SW Version")
        supportBuildName.setReadOnly(True)
        supportBuildName.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        numFilesGen = QLineEdit()
        numFilesGen.setPlaceholderText("Number of ATDS files to be generated")
        numFilesGen.setReadOnly(True)
        numFilesGen.setFixedWidth(200)
    
        # Create Layout
        headerInfo.addWidget(loadFile, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("Employee Number:"), 1, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(empNum, 1, 1)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("TDR File:"), 2, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(tdrFile, 2, 1)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("Test Name:"), 3, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(testType, 3, 1)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("Part Number:"), 4, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(partNum, 4, 1)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("Serial Number:"), 5, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(serialNum, 5, 1)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("Test Stand:"), 6, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(testStand, 6, 1)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("Test Stand Calibration Date:"), 7, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(standCal, 7, 1)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("OFP SW Version:"), 8, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(ofpBuildName, 8, 1)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("Relay Emulator Tools SW Version:"), 9, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(reBuildName, 9, 1)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("OM Build Tools SW Version:"), 10, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(omBuildToolsName, 10, 1)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("Support Tools SW Version:"), 11, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(supportBuildName, 11, 1)
        headerInfo.addWidget(QLabel("Number of ATDS Files to be Created:"), 12, 0)
        headerInfo.addWidget(numFilesGen, 12, 1)
    
        #headerInfo.setRowStretch(13, 1)
    
        # Add Header to Frame
        header.setLayout(headerInfo)
        leftLayout.addWidget(header)
    
        convertFile = QPushButton("Convert file to ATDS Format")
        #convertFiles.clicked.connect(self.convertFile)
        convertFile.setFont(QFont('Times', 16))
        leftLayout.addWidget(convertFile)
    
        # Add left layout to Main Layout
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(leftLayout, 1)
    
def _createRightLayout(self):
    
    rightLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    
    #Create ATDS File Table
    rightLayout.convTable = QTableWidget()
    
    rightLayout.convTable.setRowCount(12)
    rightLayout.convTable.setColumnCount(5)
    
    # Table to fit the screen horizontally
    rightLayout.convTable.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
    rightLayout.convTable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Interactive)
    rightLayout.convTable.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(115)
    
    # Set Column Names
    rightLayout.convTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ATDS File Name:", "ATDS File Desc:", "Conversion Status:",
                                               "Test Section:","Pass / Fail:"])
    rightLayout.addWidget(rightLayout.convTable)
    
    # Detailed information of selected files
    #Create ATDS File Table
    rightLayout.detailedInfoTable = QTableWidget()
    
    rightLayout.detailedInfoTable.setRowCount(10)
    rightLayout.detailedInfoTable.setColumnCount(7)
    
    # Table to fit the screen horizontally
    rightLayout.detailedInfoTable.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
    rightLayout.detailedInfoTable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Interactive)
    rightLayout.detailedInfoTable.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(115)
    
    # Set Column Names
    rightLayout.detailedInfoTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Test Section:", "Test Description:", "Units:",
                                               "Lower Limit:", "Upper Limit:", "Value:", "Pass / Fail:"])
    rightLayout.addWidget(rightLayout.detailedInfoTable)
    
    # Add right layout to Main Layout
    self.mainLayout.addLayout(rightLayout, 3)
    
def findFile(self):
        doc = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                                                "Load TDR File",
                                                r'S:\\EDE\\adv_sys_mfg',
                                                "Excel Files (*.xls*);; LibreOffice Files (*.ods)")        
def _createMenu(self):
    
    menu = QMenuBar(self)
    
    # Create Menus
    fileMenu = menu.addMenu("&File")
    fileMenu.addAction(self.loadAction)
    fileMenu.addSeparator()
    fileMenu.addAction(self.quit)
    
    aboutMenu = menu.addMenu("&Help")

    self.setMenuBar(menu)

def _createActions(self):
    
    self.loadAction = QAction("&Load New File", self)
    self.loadAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
    self.loadAction.triggered.connect(self.findFile)
    
    self.quit = QAction("Quit", self)
    self.quit.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
    self.quit.triggered.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)


def _createStatusBar(self):
    
    statusBar = QStatusBar()
    
    # Create Status Bar
    statusMsg = "Click Load File or Ctrl + N to begin"
    statusBar.showMessage(statusMsg)
    
    statusBar.addPermanentWidget(VLine())
            
    # Create Progress Bar
    progressBar = QProgressBar()
    statusBar.addPermanentWidget(progressBar)
    progressBar.setValue(50)
    
    statusBar.addPermanentWidget(VLine())
    
    # Add Date Time Widget to status bar
    self.display = QLabel()
    statusBar.addPermanentWidget(self.display)
    current = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
    self.display.setText(current.toString("yyyy-MMM-dd  h:mm:ss AP"))
    
    # Create date and time widget
    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(self.displayTime)
    timer.start(1000)
    self.displayTime()
    
    self.setStatusBar(statusBar)
    
def displayTime(self):
    current = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
    self.display.setText(current.toString("yyyy-MMM-dd     h:mm:ss AP"))
    
def __init__(self, atdsController):        
    # View Initializer
    super().__init__()
    
    # Connect atdsController
    self.controller = atdsController()
    
    # Set Window Properties
    self.setWindowTitle("TDR File Conversion to ATDS")
    self.setMinimumSize(1250, 600)
    
    # Set Central Widget and general layout
    self.mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
    self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
    self._centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
    
    # Create a display and buttons
    self._createActions()
    self._createLeftLayout()
    self._createRightLayout()
    self._createMenu()
    self._createStatusBar()
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:
"runfile('H:/C4ISR S2 NPI/Projects/Voice of the Process/ATDS TDR Importer - Python/ATDS File Creator/atdsController.py', wdir='H:/C4ISR S2 NPI/Projects/Voice of the Process/ATDS TDR Importer - Python/ATDS File Creator')
Reloaded modules: atdsCreatorUi
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "H:\C4ISR S2 NPI/Projects/Voice of the Process/ATDS TDR Importer - Python/ATDS File Creator\atdsCreatorUi.py", line 51, in 
loadFile.clicked.connect(lambda checked, btnTxt = loadFile.text(): self.controller.on_button_click(btnTxt))

AttributeError: 'QMainWindow' object has no attribute on_button_click'
"

From what it looks like is that atdsCreatorUi is not seeing the atdsController but I don't know why.

Any help will be appreciated,
~Dan

Comment: Try `QMainWindow()` instead of `QMainWindow`

Comment: @d-man  Thank you for your reply.  I just tried it and I was presented with an error:  
  File "H:\C4ISR S2 NPI/Projects/Voice of the Process/ATDS TDR Importer - Python/ATDS File Creator\atdsCreatorUi.py", line 278, in __init__
    self.controller = atdsController()

TypeError: 'QMainWindow' object is not callable

I then removed the "()" from line self.controller = atdsController().  Then got the original error again.

Comment: Remove `view = displayUi(QMainWindow)` and the following line, replace it with `controller = atdsController()`, add `self.view.show()`  in the `__init__` of the controller, and change to `self.controller = atdsController` without the parenteses in the `__init__` of `displayUi`. For future reference, always try to provide a [mre] (your code is way too long for a question, and 95% of it has absolutely nothing to do with your problem). Also, classes should have capitalized names, and it's good practice to put the `__init__` at the beginning of the class.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you!!!!  This was it with one more slight edit... I had to remove 'view.show()' from main() of atdsController.

I will also make the adjustments you mentioned about the class names and I will keep your suggestion for the next time I run into problems about minimum reproducible examples!

Thank you again!  How do I mark this as the answer?

Comment: @Sniperuml the above was a comment, not an answer. Considering the specificity of the problem (and the length and unnecessary complexity of the code), I sincerely doubt that this question would actually be useful to anybody else than you, which is the normal reason for an answer. On the other hand, be aware that the MVC pattern (as *any* pattern) should be chosen when it's actually necessary and useful/important to separate those elements: it should make *improve* the implementation, not complicate it. The fact that a pattern is good and valid, doesn't mean that you must always use it. ->

Comment: @Sniperuml -> The MVC used in that tutorial is useful for educational purposes, but most of the times there's actually no need for that, especially in Qt, which allows to create the "view" part externally with Designer, or integrate it in the main class(es) without the need for unnecessary complex structures. This doesn't mean that you shall not use it, but it's important to chose it with awareness, not just "because it's how it's done". Finally, functions are normally created because they're called frequently or for better code organization: those final 5 functions could be merged as one ->

Comment: @Sniperuml -> (or just be integrated in the `__init__`) and you can eventually separate each "segment" with blank lines and/or comments. A final note: that QTimer will be garbage collected as soon as `_createStatusBar()` will return, because it has no persistent reference nor a parent object, so it will never run as it will be immediately destroyed. Make it an instance attribute: `self.timer = QTimer()`